# Image rollover issue

Tags: android, jquery, css, ipad, rollover

I implemented some images rollover with CSS using the code:

```
.content3{
 background-image:url(../IMG/tablet2.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 border:5px solid #FA8072;
 border-radius:5px;
 width:220px;
 height:200px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }

.content3:hover{
background-image:url(../IMG/servizibis.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border:5px solid #FA8072;
border-radius:5px;
width:220px;
height:200px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

This works fine on the website desktop version but it doesn't work on the responsive version on Ipad and Smartphone android.
Does it exist a solution with javascript or jquery code?

Comment: How are you hovering on a tablet?

Comment: Simply digiting or pinching on the touchscreen for the Ipad 16GB